# Debugging simple game

Tags: debugging

I'm trying to make a game, its pretty simple and explained in the code. The problem is if i type a command like redright or redleft it won't work. Can you spot the problem?

Here's the code:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PillarTransferEditSpaces {

```
String top = "red          ";

String midup = "green          ";

String midlow = "yellow          ";

String low = "blue          ";

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to PillarShift. Press enter to continue");
    String key = "anything but this";

    if(key != s.nextLine()){
    System.out.println("There are three pillars with 4 colors on them, you must move the colors from the left pillar to the right pillar"); 
    }
    if(key != s.nextLine()){
        System.out.println("There are conditions.");
        }   
    if(key != s.nextLine()){
        System.out.println("1.The red color can move anywhere");
        System.out.println("2.The green color can not move where the red color is ");
        System.out.println("3.The yellow color can only be moved to an empty pillar or with the blue color");
        System.out.println("4.The blue color must move to an empty pillar");
        }   
    if(key != s.nextLine()){
        System.out.println("This is what the first move looks like if you enter 'redright'");
        }   
    if(key != s.nextLine()){
        System.out.println("  _        _         _");
        System.out.println("          red          ");
        System.out.println("  |        |         |");
        System.out.println("green                    ");
        System.out.println("  |        |         |");
        System.out.println("yellow                    ");
        System.out.println("  |        |         |");
        System.out.println("blue                    ");
        System.out.println("  |        |         |");
        System.out.println(" ---      ---       ---");
        }   
    if(key != s.nextLine()){
        System.out.println("To make a move type the color and direction without a space and hit enter. ex: redright or blueleft");
        }   

    String top = "red                    ";

    String midup = "green                    ";

    String midlow = "yellow                    ";

    String low = "blue                    "; 


    while(top != "                    red" && midup != "                    green" && midlow != "                    yellow" && low != "                    blue" ){

        String move = s.nextLine();


    if (move == "redleft"){
        top = moveRedLeft(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }
    if (move == "redright"){

        top = moveRedRight(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }if (move == "greenright"){
        midup = moveGreenRight(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }if (move == "greenleft"){
        midup = moveGreenLeft(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }if (move == "yellowleft"){
        midlow = moveYellowLeft(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }if (move == "yellowright"){
        midlow = moveYellowRight(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }if (move == "blueleft"){
        low = moveBlueLeft(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }if (move == "blueright"){
        low = moveBlueRight(top, midup, midlow, low);
    }
    System.out.println("  _        _         _");
    System.out.println(top);
    System.out.println("  |        |         |");
    System.out.println(midup);
    System.out.println("  |        |         |");
    System.out.println(midlow);
    System.out.println("  |        |         |");
    System.out.println(low);
    System.out.println("  |        |         |");
    System.out.println(" ---      ---       ---");

    }

    System.out.println("Congrats, you solved it. Was it hard? :P");
}


    private static String moveRedRight(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){

        if(top == "red                    "){
        top = ("          red          ");

        return top;}

        if(top == ("          red          ")){
            top = "                    red";

        return top;
        }
        if (top == "                    red"){
            System.out.println("No pillar to the right, where's it supposed to go?");

        return top;
        }
        return top;
        }


    private static String moveRedLeft(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){
        if(top == "                    red"){
        top = ("          red          ");
        return top;
        }

        if(top == ("          red          ")){
            top = "red                    ";
            return top;
        }
        if (top == "red                    "){
            System.out.println("No pillar to the left, where's it supposed to go?");

        return top;
        }
        return top;
        }

    private static String moveGreenLeft(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){

            if(top == "                    red" && midup == "                    green"){
            midup = ("          green          ");
            return midup;
            }

            if(top == "red                    " && midup == "                    green"){
            midup = ("          green          ");
            return midup;
            }
            if(top == "          red          " && midup == "                    green"){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");
                return midup;
            }
            if (top == "                    red" && midup == "          green          "){
                midup = "green                    ";
                return midup;
            }
            if (top == "red                    " && midup == "          green          "){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");
                return midup;
            }
            if (top == "          red          " && midup == "          green          "){
                midup = "green                    ";
                return midup;
            }
        return midup;
    }

    private static String moveGreenRight(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){

                    if(top == "                    red" && midup == "                    green"){
                    System.out.println("No pillar to the right, where's it supposed to go?");
                    return midup;
                    }

                    if(top == "red                    " && midup == "                    green"){
                    System.out.println("No pillar to the right, where's it supposed to go?");
                    return midup;
                    }
                    if(top == "          red          " && midup == "                    green"){
                    System.out.println("No pillar to the right, where's it supposed to go?");
                    return midup;
                    }
                    if (top == "                    red" && midup == "          green          "){
                        System.out.println("invalid movement");
                        return midup;
                    }
                    if (top == "red                    " && midup == "          green          "){
                        midup = "                    green";
                        return midup;
                    }
                    if (top == "          red          " && midup == "          green          "){
                        midup = "                    green";
                        return midup;
                    }
                    if (top == "                    red" && midup == "green                    "){
                        midup = "          green          ";
                        return midup;

                    }
                    if (top == "red                    " && midup == "green                    "){
                        midup = "          green          ";
                        return midup;
                    }
                    if (top == "          red          " && midup == "green                    "){
                        System.out.println("invalid movement");
                        return midup;
                    }
                    return midup;

}

    private static String moveYellowRight(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){

            if(midlow == "yellow                    "){

                if(top == "          red          " || midup == "          green          "){
                    System.out.println("invalid movement");return midlow;
                }
            }else{
                midlow = "          yellow          ";return midlow;
            }

            if(midlow == "          yellow          "){

                if(top == "                    red" || midup == "                    green"){
                    System.out.println("invalid movement");return midlow;
                }
            }else{
                midlow = "                    yellow";return midlow;
            }
            if(midlow == "                    yellow"){
                System.out.println("No pillar to the right, where's it supposed to go?");
            }
            return midlow;
}
    private static String moveYellowLeft(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){

        if(midlow == "                    yellow"){

            if(top == "          red          " || midup == "          green          "){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");return midlow;
            }
        }else{
            midlow = "          yellow          ";return midlow;
        }

        if(midlow == "          yellow          "){

            if(top == "red                    " || midup == "green                    "){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");return midlow;
            }
        }else{
            midlow = "yellow                    ";return midlow;
        }
        if(midlow == "yellow                    "){
            System.out.println("No pillar to the left, where's it supposed to go?");
        }
        return midlow;
```

}
        private static String moveBlueLeft(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){

```
        if(low == "                    blue"){

            if(top == "          red          " || midup == "          green          " || midlow == "          yellow          "){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");return low;
            }
        }else{
            low = "          blue          ";return low;
        }

        if(low == "          blue          "){

            if(top == "red                    " || midup == "green                    " || midlow == "yellow                    "){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");return low;
            }
        }else{
            low = "blue                    ";return low;
        }
        if(midlow == "blue                    "){
            System.out.println("No pillar to the left, where's it supposed to go?");
            return low;
        }
        return low;
        }


    private static String moveBlueRight(String top,String midup,String midlow,String low){

        if(low == "blue                    "){

            if(top == "          red          " || midup == "          green          " || midlow == "          yellow          "){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");return low;}

        }else{
            low = "          blue          ";return low;
        }

        if(low == "          blue          "){

            if(top == "                    red" || midup == "                    green" || midlow == "                    yellow"){
                System.out.println("invalid movement");return low;
            }
        }else{
            low = "                    blue";return low;
        }
        if(low == "                    blue"){
            System.out.println("No pillar to the right, where's it supposed to go?");
            return low;
        }
        return low;
    }
```

}

Comment: Try using "equals" instead of == in your string comparison. Ex: if(low.equals("blue                    "){} etc.

Comment: Genius! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :). Keep up the good work

Comment: From the StackOverflow Asking Help page: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Use string function "equals" instead of "==" in the string comparison. Ex: if(low.equals("blue "){} etc. :)